# MTP unlocked by default - How to lock it?

Tags: samsung, security, lock-screens, custom-roms, mtp

I have a Samsung j730f and currently I am using a custom ROM and if I plug my phone into a computer (even with the screen locked), I can access to my data.

Please help me: how can I lock the MTP?

Comment: Which custom ROM are you using? Check developer options for this setting.